# how to generate cookie using node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cookies, passport.js

how to generate cookie using node js , I am using express-session node plugin to generate the cookie .please tell me where I am doing wrong

install `express-session` plugin

app.js

```
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'asdassadsazz',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    //cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**passport.js**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('ddd');
//    console.log(user);
    done(null, id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

controller.js

```
 register: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        try {
            const result = await db.User.create({
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password
            })

           console.log(result.id);
            req.login(result.id,function () {
                res.json({message:"Registration successfully"});

            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

    },
```

It should generate cookie and store in browser,but it is not generating any cookie.[image]

[image]

server log

```
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Users` FROM `sql12252060`
app is running on 5000
OPTIONS /users/register 204 1.943 ms - 0
{ email: 'a@g.com', password: '1' }
email element
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'a@g.com','$2a$10$zhTaqEbEeMOaD8F..CQYRufALc5dD4l899qMKRw0QRxIWvrPMSlpq');
17
ddd
POST /users/register 200 932.036 ms - 39
```

is the issue of different domain .my server is running on 5000 port and client is running on 3000

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set. If you have your node.js behind a proxy and are using secure: true, you need to set "trust proxy" in express:

   var app = express()
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
  app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

resave option should be false.
resave:
Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the session was never modified during the request. Depending on your store this may be necessary, but it can also create race conditions where a client makes two parallel requests to your server and changes made to the session in one request may get overwritten when the other request ends, even if it made no changes (this behavior also depends on what store you're using).

The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated, as the default will change in the future. Please research into this setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case. Typically, you'll want false.

How do I know if this is necessary for my store? The best way to know is to check with your store if it implements the touch method. If it does, then you can safely set resave: false. If it does not implement the touch method and your store sets an expiration date on stored sessions, then you likely need resave: true.